# Creating Subsite button has disappreared in our sharepoint 2013 environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

hope eveyrone is doing well.

In our testing environment I'm unable to create new subsite.

when I go to site contents, at the below I can able to see the Subsite menu, but I'm not getting any button like create subsite.

We were able to have this feature few days ago, but I dont know suddenly how its disappeared.
[image]
May I please know how to get back creating subsite button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check

- if your permission changed
- if you deploy some solution / feature in the farm which remove this functionality.
- check if the site collection quota reached or site collection marked as read only
- Try creating sub-site directly from this url `http://{SiteURL}/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx`

Check if you can create new subsite by going site settings > site content > under subsite heading click on new subsite.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

1.Actually I tried using sp farm ID but I'm unable to create it.
2.yes recently I restored web application from production to testing.
3.May I please know what will be the site collection quota in web application?
I will try to create subsite directly then let you know.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there are some code which hides the button in the page?

And go to 
**Central Administration->
Manage web applications->
[your web application]->**

Permission Policy, check all permission policy levels, and make sure there is no permission policy level which denies "Create Subsites" permission for Site Collection Administrator or Site Colllection Auditor.

In addition, please create a new site collection within the same web application, and check if the button exists.